# Add field to solr managed-schema by sorj is not working

Tags: solr, solrj

I use SOLR 8.5.0 and solrj client. I managed to create new core in standalone mode by solrj and I wanted to add fields to my schema. The code is the following:

```
//General solrClient not including core name
CoreAdminRequest.Create.createCore(this.name, this.name, solrClient);

//other solrClient including the created core name as a part of the baseUrl
SolrClient solrC=new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/petshop").build();

for(SolrField field : solrFields) {
        Map<String, Object> fieldAttributes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        fieldAttributes.put("name", field.getFieldName());
        fieldAttributes.put("type", field.getDataType().getSolrType());
        fieldAttributes.put("stored", field.isStored());
        fieldAttributes.put("indexed", field.isIndexed());
        fieldAttributes.put("multiValued", field.isMultiValued());
        fieldAttributes.put("omitNorms", field.isOmitNorms());
        fieldAttributes.put("docValues", field.isDocValues());
        fieldAttributes.put("required", false);
        fieldAttributes.put("uninvertable", false);
        try {
            SchemaRequest.AddField schemaRequest = new SchemaRequest.AddField(fieldAttributes);
            SchemaResponse.UpdateResponse response =  schemaRequest.process(solrC);
            System.out.println("Schema request url: "+response.getRequestUrl());
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

When I check the admin UI, the core was created properly. Only modifying the schema was not succeeded.
Unfortunately, I get a very useless exception:  org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteExecutionException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/petshop: error processing commands.
Does anybody have idea what goes wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance,
Roland

Comment: What error message does the server log - i.e. not just the client - show? The problem could be with what fields you're trying to add - i.e. they already exist from the default config, you have duplicate or invalid field names, the type doesn't exist, etc.

Comment: @MatsLindh Indeed I had a typo. Instead of uninvertable the correct term uninvertible. This caused the problem and this info comes from the Solr log. I fixed it and it works now. Thanks